# Converting 2 different variables into 1 variable and with string in between[Python 3.x]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 variables in config file

```
cfg: /api/config/devices/{}/test
amd: /api/bind/templateData/{}/test2
```

In my function I call the below way

```
self.configs[cfg].format(tmpl_name) + self.configs[amd].format(tmpl2_name)
```

this translates to

> /api/config/devices/{}/test/{tmpl_name}/api/bind/templateData/{}/test2/{tmpl2_name}

There is a string in between, is there a way I can create a single Variable and include the tmpl_name in between?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What exactly do you want your single variable to contain?

Comment: Looks like you might want to use f-strings: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting

Comment: so  in variable cfg,  I can try changing to cfg: /api/config/devices/f{tmpl_name} /api/bind/templateData/ ?

Comment: tmpl_name is function argument def abc1(tmpl_name):

Answer (score 2):

## Use F-Strings

You can do so like this:

```py
f"Text you want here {tmpl_name} text you want here {self.configs[amd]}"
```

You can insert text and string variables at any point in the string, which should give you your desired output, for example:

```py
f"/api/config/devices/{tmpl_name}/api/bind/templateData/"
```

or however else you might wish to format it.

You can read more about f-strings [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting).

Answer (score 0):

let us assume that you have these two variables in a config file like given below:
[general]
cfg: /api/config/devices/
amd: /api/bind/templateData/

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(<config file path")
tmpl_name = "test"
print ((config.get("general","cfg")+"{}"+config.get("general","amd")).format(tmpl_name))
```

output: /api/config/devices/test/api/bind/templateData/

Answer (score 0):

thanks all string format helped me.
[CONFIG].format(arg1,arg2)